# Problem joining tables where joined table needs to be ordered before grouping

Tags: sql, join, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a scenario, which is seemingly simple on paper, but I'm having trouble getting to work as desired in practice.

I have two tables (only relevant columns presented):

```
| Thread
+----------
| ThreadID 

| Post
+----------
| PostID
| ThreadID
| Posted (Datetime)
```

Now, what I want to do, is to join Thread and Post, grouping by ThreadID. But I want to order by Post.Posted in descending order. In plain english, I want to join Thread on the most recent Post relating to it.

My SQL so far:

```
SELECT Thread.ThreadID, Post.PostID, Post.Created
FROM Thread
LEFT JOIN Post ON Post.ThreadID = Thread.ThreadID
GROUP BY Thread.ThreadID
ORDER BY Post.Created DESC
```

It does the job, but the order of the join is not correct, as the ordering is, of course, applied only after the grouping is performed.

Surely, there must be a way to accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select t.ThreadID, p.PostID, p.Posted
from Thread t
inner join (
    select ThreadID, Max(Posted) as MaxPosted
    from Post
    group by ThreadID       
) pm on t. ThreadID = pm.ThreadID
inner join Post p on pm.ThreadID = p.ThreadID and pm.MaxPosted = p.Posted
order by p.Posted desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Use both the thread id and the created date in the order by clause

```
SELECT Thread.ThreadID, Post.PostID, Post.Created
FROM Thread
LEFT JOIN Post ON Post.ThreadID = Thread.ThreadID
GROUP BY Thread.ThreadID
ORDER BY Thread.ThreadID, Post.Created DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Would you be able to explain this a bit further?

Comment: @nikc: I thought the requirement was *"I want to join Thread on the most **recent** Post"*? This will not necessarily give you the latest. In fact, I don't think that PostID and Created will necessarily refer to the same record in this query.

Comment: @OrbMan: yes, that is the requirement. On my limited test data, it seemed to do the trick.