# SQL request with "Group by" and "max" and "join"?

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, inner-join

Here is a sample of my DATA:

CLIENT_ATTRIBUT :

```
ID_CLIENT | DATE_CLIENT | ATTRIBUT
----------+-------------+---------
000000001 | 2010:03:01  | 0000010
----------+-------------+---------
000000001 | 2010:02:16  | 0000010
----------+-------------+---------
000000001 | 2010:03:04  | 0000011
----------+-------------+---------
000000002 | 2010:03:01  | 0001000
----------+-------------+---------
```

CLIENT :

```
ID_CLIENT | NOM_MARITAL |
----------+-------------+
000000001 | PANTROMANI  | 
----------+-------------+
000000002 | ELLOUQUIER  |
----------+-------------+
```

I'd like to get, for each ID_CLIENT in the table "CLIENT_ATTRIBUT" :
ID_CLIENT, max(DATE_CLIENT) with its corresponding "ATTRIBUT", and "NOM_MARITAL"

So in the example above :

```
ID_CLIENT | DATE_CLIENT | ATTRIBUT | NOM_MARITAL |
----------+-------------+----------+-------------+
000000001 | 2010:03:04  | 0000011  | PANTROMANI  |
----------+-------------+----------+-------------+
000000002 | 2010:03:01  | 0001000  | ELLOUQUIER  |
```

(i'm working with Mysql but i guess it should not be so different with any Database System)

Comment: Smells like homework and has been answered on this site numerous times.

Comment: See [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341659/problem-joining-tables-where-joined-table-needs-to-be-ordered-before-grouping) for answers.

Comment: It is unfortunate this is MySQL, in postgresql you could `SELECT DISTINCT ON( id_client ) date_client, attribut, non_marital FROM client_attribut JOIN client USING ( id_client ) ORDER BY date_client DESC`. This would be massively faster and clearer than the current solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use a sub-query as follows:

```
SELECT 
    client.id_client,
    sub_query.date_client,
    client_attribut.attribut,
    client.nom_marital
FROM
    client
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         client_attribut.id_client, 
         MAX(client_attribut.date_client) as date_client
     FROM 
         client_attribut
     GROUP BY 
         client_attribut.id_client)
     AS sub_query ON (sub_query.id_client = client.id_client)
INNER JOIN
    client_attribut ON (client_attribut.id_client = sub_query.id_client AND
                        client_attribut.date_client = sub_query.date_client);
```

Comment: Looks like this solution doesn't give the right "ATTRIBUT" value : In the example above, it would give "0000010" instead of "0000011" for ID_CLIENT = "000000001"

Comment: @dangolive: My fault! Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you very much, It does the work now ! Still a little bit complicated for me, i'll study it closer :)